# Bind data in Adaptive cards in Bot framework

Tags: json, botframework

How can we bind data to the adaptive cards from backend ? I have designed a card from `https://adaptivecards.io/designer` which returns a `JSON` file.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question please? Do you need to know how to use the json you built?

Comment: Are you using the NodeJS or the C# SDK version of the framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AdaptiveCards are essentially just JSON Objects, so adding your content to it is as simple as editing the JSON created with the AdaptiveCard Designer.  In NodeJs this is pretty simple; however, in C# you need to use `JObject` and `JArray` to parse and modify the JSON file from the designer.

#### Adaptive Card

Here is a simple AdaptiveCard I created with the designer that I will use in my examples for NodeJs and C# below.

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "text": "My Adaptive Card",
            "isSubtle": true
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "New TextBlock"
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

#### NodeJS BotFramework SDK V4

Once we read the AdaptiveCard in from the JSON file, we can directly change the values in the card or add additional components. Then we can use the CardFactory to render the card and send it to the user.

```
const { CardFactory } = require('botbuilder');
const Card = require('./resources/my-adaptive-card');

...

// Change Text Field
Card.body[1].text = "Item 1";

// Add Text Field
Card.body.push({
    type: "TextBlock",
    text: "Item 2"
});

await turnContext.sendActivity({attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(Card)]});
```

#### C# BotFramework SDK V4

Since we can't directly modify JSON in C# as we can in NodeJS, we have to use the `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` namespace so we can make changes to the card with `JObject` and `JArray`.  Once we've made the necessary changes, the card can be rendered and sent to the user as an AdaptiveCard.

For more information on modifying JSON in C#, check out the [JSON.Net Documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm).

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

...

// Parse AdaptiveCard JSON from file
var adaptiveCardJson = File.ReadAllText(@".\Resources\AdaptiveCard.json");
JObject json = JObject.Parse(adaptiveCardJson);

// Get the `body` of the AdaptiveCard
JArray body = (JArray)json["body"];

// Change Text Field
((JObject)body[1])["text"] = "Item 1";

// Add Text Field
body.Add(JObject.Parse("{\"type\": \"TextBlock\", \"text\": \"Item 2\"}"));

var adaptiveCardAttachment = new Attachment()
{
    ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
    Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json.ToString()),
};

var reply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply();
reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>() { adaptiveCardAttachment };
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
```

#### Result

AdaptiveCard before changes
[image: Adaptive Card before changes]

AdaptiveCard after changes
[image: AdaptiveCard after changes]